# Xamarin Profiler not starting - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

Xamarin profiler is not starting from Visual Studio 2013. 
I am getting below messages in my OUTPUT

> "An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details. 
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Had anybody faced this before ? 
Where can i find the logs ?

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Even thought not an exact solution just a workaround

When starting the xamarin Profiler from Xamarin studio works.

I think there is some problem with Xamarin Profiler when starting from Visual studio.

Regards

Vipin Kumar

Comment: Thanks for the info. That helped!

Comment: Where can one Download Xamarin Studio? I cannot find any MS links to download Xamarin Studio.